# accessing iframe element not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I am using iframe, this iframe will have a img tag so i have to set a data from a parent html page to iframe.
I am achieving this by following

My Html is,

```
<img id='im' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ.....'/>
```

My script is,

```
jQuery(".edit").click(function(){
    jQuery("#editor").removeClass('disable');
    frames = window.frames;
    src = jQuery('#im').attr('src');   
    jQuery(frames[0].document.getElementById('canv')).attr("src",src);
});
```

The above code correctly pass image data and set the target element in iframe in firefox, but in chrome the target image does not change..What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is a little tricky when it comes to iframes. Add a doctype to the top of your iframe document and it should work.

If that does not work, it is likely an issue with Chrome security settings blocking mixed content. From what I understand, Chrome will not load I frames that are not https.

Comment: Are you trying to access content from a different site?

Comment: Could also be Chrome's security feature to block mixed content. It no longer likes loading http pages (as opposed to https) in iFrames as a security risk.

Comment: no from my site only it just show the clicked image to a new iframe

Comment: Can you possibly post more of your code on jsfiddle or CodePen so we can get a better look at the bigger picture?